# Julia and HTCondor - ENV["HOME"] causes error on Condor

Tags: julia, condor

When I run a Julia Script that prints "Hello World" on [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/), I get the following error

```
fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.
Base.InitError(mod=:Pkg, error=Base.KeyError(key="HOME"))
```

The code runs without a problem on my local Ubuntu machine. I can run

```
 eval  julia --version
```

in a bash script on condor and the output is

```
julia version 0.5.0
```

This problem has been discussed in two places on github: [one](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15884), [two](https://github.com/JuliaParallel/ClusterManagers.jl/issues/51).
ENV["HOME"] is used in a single [file](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/e90bcf3fd91363dd4cd0a28d0ac0f942561467d6/base/path.jl#L28) and the common recommendation is to modify that. However, I cannot change the julia installation on condor.

Is there a way to fix this on the fly before running a script without sudo?

Comment: Is it possible to specify env variables in your condor script?

Comment: Thank you @sujeet, prompted by you I found a way to set the environmental variable in condor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sujeet suggested, it is possible to [set environmental parameters](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/condor_submit.html#man-condor-submit-environment) in condor. The issue is resolved by adding the following line in the condor submit script

```
Environment = "HOME=""/tmp"""
```

, which sets the home directory to the tmp. Julia code runs fine then (as long one is careful not to write to home before resetting it in the script itself).